# Owl carousel autoplay speed stuck at 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to shorten the speed of the autoplay on an owl carousel (I'm using owl carousel 1), but it's always stuck at 5 seconds. On the website (which is broken) it says you can add an integer after `autoplay:` but it doesn't matter what number I add, it always takes 5 seconds to play.

And I should mention that `autoPlay` (with capital P) does not work for me like it's shown on their website. Only if I use `autoplay` it actually auto plays.

These are the settings of my owl carousel:

```
$("#owl-mockup").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        autoplay: 3000,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
            },
            600:{
                items:1,
            },
            1000:{
                items:3,
            }
        }
    });
```

Why is it not listening to the number added?

Answer (score 8):

Try using:

```
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 3000
```

instead:

```
autoplay: 3000
```

In owl docs says that autoplay expect a boolean value. In any case, for change the timing i'm using autoplayTimeout and it work perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, been hacking at Owl Carousel for 48 hours now and nearly there. Regading the speed, whilst I had the Owl JS embedded in the page, I still had the external JS sheet from the initial set up that I forgot about further down the page. No matter what I did, I was stuck at 5 seconds. Once I removed it,

```
 autoplay: true,
 autoplayTimeout: 3000
```

the above controls worked fine.